# C# FileSystemWatcher does not fire Rename events after two changes back and forth

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

When I change extension of file in the sequence old => new => old, the third time I don't get notified, even if I change the extension to something completely different. I have to change file name to make it go further.

Any ideas?

My watcher wrapper:

```
    public class WatcherWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _fileWatcher;
    private readonly Subject<FileSystemEventArgs> _infoSubject;
    private Subject<FileSystemEventArgs> _eventSubject;

    public WatcherWrapper(string path, string nameFilter = "*.*", NotifyFilters? notifyFilters = null)
    {
        _fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, nameFilter);

        if (notifyFilters != null)
        {
            _fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = notifyFilters.Value;
        }

        _infoSubject = new Subject<FileSystemEventArgs>();
        _eventSubject = new Subject<FileSystemEventArgs>();


        Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(_fileWatcher, "Changed").Select(e => e.EventArgs)
            .Distinct(e => e.FullPath).Subscribe(_infoSubject.OnNext);
        Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(_fileWatcher, "Created").Select(e => e.EventArgs)
            .Distinct(e => e.FullPath).Subscribe(_infoSubject.OnNext);
        Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(_fileWatcher, "Deleted").Select(e => e.EventArgs)
            .Distinct(e => e.FullPath).Subscribe(_infoSubject.OnNext);
        Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(_fileWatcher, "Renamed").Select(e => e.EventArgs)
            .Distinct(e => e.FullPath).Subscribe(_infoSubject.OnNext);


        _infoSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
            .Select(x =>
            {
                return x.GroupBy(z => z.Name).Select(z => z.LastOrDefault());
            }).Subscribe(
                infos =>
                {
                    if (infos != null)
                        foreach (var info in infos)
                        {
                            {
                                _eventSubject.OnNext(info);
                            }
                        }
                });

        _fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> FileEvents => _eventSubject;

    public async Task<bool> WaitForFile(string path, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var end = DateTime.UtcNow + timeout;

        try
        {
            while (DateTime.UtcNow <= end)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(200);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _fileWatcher?.Dispose();
        _eventSubject.Dispose();
        _infoSubject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I've put conditional break point in the line after Buffer (Count > 0), but nothing gets there. If I change the name of the file, it fires at once.

Comment: If you don't use `Observable` do you experience the same issue?

Comment: thanks, my bad. I forgot abour Distinct in FromEventPattern :)